# Adding New Properties to a Function Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the following pattern:

```
// https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-collapse.js

  $.fn.collapse = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('collapse')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('collapse', (data = new Collapse(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  $.fn.collapse.defaults = {
    toggle: true
  }
```

It looks like `collapse` is a function object. Then, why `defaults` can be added as a property to `collapse`?

The following [(jsFiddle) snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/KTzUw/) tries to add a new property to a function object but to no avail. What is it?

```
var my_object = function () {
    alert('Hello World!');
};
my_object.name = 'my_object';

console.log(my_object.name);  // prints an empty string
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful answers. It's a little hard to choose the best one when majority of them are really good. +1 for the non-accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a function *object*. All objects in javascript can have properties, and so `$.fn.collapse` has `defaults`.

Your fiddle does not work because every function [object] has a non-writable [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) which contains the name of the function - if it were named. You are assigning an anonymous function to the `my_object` variable, which has an empty name. Notice it *is* a string, not `undefined`! Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/KTzUw/3/

Comment: Ah, now I understand that `var my_object = function () { ... }` is different from `var my_object = function my_object() { ... }` in a way the latter has `my_object.name` set i.e. not an empty string.

Comment: Yes. You might want to read [this article about *named function expressions*](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Comment: Thanks (+1)! Is there a way to investigate which properties has special flags? I mean, where can I look for the _non-configurable_ or _non-writable_ flags?

Comment: You can check them using [getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) and [getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

Answer (score 2):

`.name` is special, most other property names work:

```
var my_object = function () {
    alert('Hello World!');
};
my_object.someprop = 'my_object';
console.log(my_object.someprop);  // prints an empty string
```

The `name` property of functions is reserved.

```
function foo() {};
console.log(foo.name); // "foo"
```

In your case it's an empty string because it's declared as an anonymous function:

```
var foo = function() {};
console.log(foo.name); // ""
```

But other than a few reserved property names, yes, you can assign properties of functions like you can any object. This can be pretty powerful, as it lets you sort of tie data to the code that needs that data in a pretty clean way.

Answer (score 1):

`name` is a reserved *property* for *function instances* and has *non-configurable* and *non-writable* flags, you can't overwrite it. Beside from that, a *function* does also inherit from *Object* and may have properties.

```
var my_fnc = function() { };

my_fnc.foobar = 42;

console.log( my_fnc_foobar ); // 42
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to investigate which properties has special flags? I mean, where can I look for the _non-configurable_ or _non-writable_ flags?