# Why can't I use "name" as static attribute in javascript / nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, naming, static-variables

I couldn't figure out this, but maybe anyone can help me: 
When I define a javascript class and try to add a static attribute "name", I can't use "name" afterwards.

```
var MyClass = function() {
  this.name = 'This is an instance of MyClass';
  this.anyName = 'This has nothing to do with it';
}

// static attributes
MyClass.name = 'Why is this not possible?';
MyClass.anyName = 'This works fine!';

var a = new MyClass();
console.log(a.name);
console.log(a.anyName);
console.log(MyClass.name);
console.log(MyClass.anyName);
```

I would expect it to output all 4 strings. But instead it will only output:

```
This is an instance of MyClass
This has nothing to do with it

This works fine!
```

It doesn't accept the static attribute "name", but why? Any ideas/hints?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding New Properties to a Function Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352643/adding-new-properties-to-a-function-object), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name property of function objects is **read-only**, the assignment on it will be ignored.

Comment: I gotta say, thats pretty lame. Even when you "use strict"; it still silently fails.